# Thesis Acceptance Signature Sheet

Tags: thesis, forms, signatures

I would like to produce a acceptance sheet for my thesis to be signed by the persons involved. I've tried the code provided in some similar questions but those weren't compatible with the desired acceptance sheet.

How do I an acceptance sheet of this kind?

[image: Acceptance Sheet]

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please add code to your question, e.g. the one with shortcomings? What are the typographical requirements for the acceptance sheet? Please add that info, too. Thank you

Comment: The typological requirement is that there must be the names of the persons involved underlined and that it must be double spaced and in Times New Roman font size 12.